# Finding a polynomial $P(x)$ with real coefficients satisfying $P(x)P(x+1)=P(x^2+2)$

Tags: functional-equations

$P(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients satisfying $$P(x)P(x+1)=P(x^2+2)$$

I did find some solutions for $P(x)P(x+1)=P(x^2)$ and I wonder if I can do the same for this problem

I tried making $P(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$, and got that $a_n=1$, but I don't know how to make progress

P/s: I do found that $(x^2-x+2)^n$ is a solution. The solution is here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h392562p2239953.

Comment: $P(x)=0$ and $P(x)=1$ are two possible solutions.

Comment: Oh yes, I had done that too. If P(x) = c(const) ...

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. By "Find P(x) with real coefficients", I assume the "real coefficients" are referring to that where $P(x)$ is a polynomial. Please clarify that.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thank you very much! Actually, I study math in Vietnamese so there are many math terms that I don't understand.

Comment: You're welcome. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p(x)p(x%2B1)%3Dp(x%5E2%2B2)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Apolynomial%2C%20OR%20content%3Areal%20coefficients&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [P(x) that satisfies ...](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h493879p2771598), [Polynomials!](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1149883p5437101) and [Polynomial equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1486243p8701401) (with this one giving a source of "Swiss TST $2015$. Problem $6$").

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you. This is the problem my teacher gave me yesterday to prepare for VMO.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Please edit your question with some of the material you have in the comments (I received from teacher / I already know that constants are solutions). If the question is online by any chance and not in your textbook then you can attach the link to it. Thanks. Also, what method was used to solve the similar equation $P(x)P(x+1) = P(x^2)$?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer For that problem, if $z$ is a root of $P$, then so are $z^2$ and $(z-1)^2$. There are a lot of values of $z$ for which if $z$ is a root, then $P$ would have infinitely many roots. After you rule these out, there are not too many possible roots.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thanks for the clarification. I think a similar method can be used here but it will be a little more complicated.

Comment: @Kii if you seem to have found the solution, please post your answer below.